# Git - how to block merging from master into another branch

Tags: git, merge

As `.gitignore` doesn't work per branch and I need to keep a file in `master` that shouldn't be in other branches, I wish to block any merging of `master` into other branches.

I am expecting some `.git*` like file which I can set in the repository itself that a merge of master into another branch would be rejected or at least a warning would appear.

Is there anyone knows if that is possible anyhow?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say `.gitignore` doesn't work per branch.  Your `.gitignore` can absolutely contain different rules in two different branches.

Comment: AFAIK it always works for all branches the same way. Do you know a way to set .gitignore to work in different ways for different branches?

Comment: `.gitignore` is just an ordinary file checked in to a branch like any other.  You can have different contents on one branch from another.  Just edit it, add, and commit it.

Comment: yep, naturally, but that's not the same as having *one* .gitignore saying "file Readme is included (appears) in `master` but not in `staging`" (exactly by the reason you pointed out: it's just a file you add and checkin as any other).

Comment: just ensure you don't get me wrong: s/is included/is not ignored/

Comment: I see.  Yes.  `.gitignore` won't help you here.  What you need to prevent merging master into other branches is an update hook on the server.  If you want to catch this on the client before an attempted push, I'm not sure what the right hook would be ... maybe pre-commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can write server side hook script to restrict the commit of given branch. You can even modify it to restrict the merge from specific branch (master).

You can find the detail here.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy